# Setup pop3 mailboxes in on Windows Server 2012 datacenter

Tags: windows-server-2012, pop3, mailbox

a complete beginner question but I cannot find an answer with Google:
Where do I setup email accounts / POP3 mailboxes on Windows Server 2012? I setup smtp service and can send emails from the server but I want to create private email mailboxes for several users? Thanks for any help

Comment: If you are a novice user [this tutorial](http://blog.evomailserver.com/how-to-setup-mail-server-in-windows/) might help. It tells you how to configure an IMAP/POP3 email server on Windows Server from scratch, including DNS settings and Firewll rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in mail server in Windows. Use Microsoft Exchange, or some other third party mail server that supports Windows.

Comment: I didn't know that. Could you recommend a good free mail server? I don't need any advanced features. It just has to be a stable one. Sorry, I am not a sys admin, just have to setup a server for a small client and need some guidance

Comment: @lesko products recommendations are off topic here, but luckily for you, [google](http://www.google.com) is in good working order.

Comment: I did google search before asking. Thank you for the first reply as well as letting me know this forum's rules